# Unity ECS - The type could not be found - CS02

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ecs

I have many problems with my Unity ECS like this one.
Firstly, in a script like that (with many imports for tests) :

```
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Rendering;
using Unity.Transforms;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour, IConvertGameObjectToEntity
{
    //      ...
}
```

The type "IConvertGameObjectToEntity" isn't reconize by Unity, why ? I import Entities, Entities Graphics (latests versions) and I have HybridRendering. For information, others types and attributes don't work, like "[GenerateAuthoringComponent]", thanks in advance.

I have recreated 3 times the projects. I have uninstalled the Entities packages and reinstall them. I have changed the version of Unity (the latest LTS). I have regenerate the projects files after import the all packages. I don't know what to do... Morefurther I also check Internet and Stackoverflow with her potentials answers.

Comment: what are you using to edit ? is the error in unity or the code editor? rider can be a bit pants about stuff - oh and are you using a current tutorial? its changed a lot since its early days...

Comment: @BugFinder I use Visual Studio 2022, it's an error of Unity Editor and the IDE (VS2022), so the both. I don't follow a tutorial specificaly, but I have read many web sites, YouTube videos and saw recents code exemples on Internet and forum. I use the latests versions of all packages and of Unity !

Comment: well entitles 1.0.16 doesnt seem to have IConvertGameObjectToEntity as an interface.. so. thats why

Comment: @BugFinder thank you, how I see if a package contains a certain definition in a specific version ? It's the same for "[GenerateAuthoringComponent]" attribute ?

Comment: too lazy to work your own tool?  as i said i use raider.. but hey.. apparently open the references, find unity.entites, double click on it, it opens an object browser

Comment: @BugFinder ? I don't want to use [GenerateAuthoringComponent], it's just I didn't understand why certains packages couldn't be found... I didn't know JetBrain Rider, but OK I'll see that ! Now, I try to create my own tool, but certains packages so I didn't know if that mayby can cause troubles in my scripts. But thank you for all. I'll cloes the ask conversation. I was not sure

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the types and attributes in question are no more in `Unity.Entities`, like `[GenerateAuthoringComponent]`, `Translation` or `IConvertGameObjectToEntity`, ...